# Invalid operands to binary expression ('float *' and 'float *')

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4

In my appDelegate.m file I have the following code:

```
@synthesize celsius = _celsius;
@synthesize fahrenheit = _fahrenheit;
@synthesize multiplyer = _multiplyer;
```

And then later on...

```
- (IBAction)celciusChange:(id)sender {

[self setFahrenheit:self.celsius * self.multiplyer)];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  All the variables are floats, and as you can see, this is a temperature converter program.

Comment: Show the @property declarations for all these variables. The error message implies that you set them to the type `float *`, not `float` -- but that's just a guess.

Comment: Is that unpaired right parenthesis after "self.multiplyer" a typo?

Answer (score 3):

You've probably declared your properties as pointers:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) float * celsius;
```

not values:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) float celsius;
```

Comment: @CurtRevis agh! my friend put Mountain Lion on his computer and now the Xcode that I have is not supported. (I am not asking for help, but now you can see why I cant give you the \@property declarations.)